# Google Plus (+1) API - verified names?

Tags: google-plus

Some profiles on Google Plus are verified. ( Just like twitter )
But unlike twitter, I couldn't find a way to retrieve the verified indication.
I've scanned the API - but couldn't find it. ( https://developers.google.com/+/api/ )

Anyone tried to find / mess around with verified names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verification status is not something that's available via the REST API.

You may want to request it in the API's [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

G+ has added support for verification:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people

Answer (score -1):

It's up to Google to decide who deserves to be verified. Apparently it depends a lot on number of people who have added you into their Circles.

http://google-plus.com/3083/how-to-apply-or-get-a-verified-profile-or-verified-google-page/

Comment: Any reason for downvoting ?